# Can anyone help me out for side flip function using svg.js

Tags: html, jquery-ui, svg.js

I have written a flipUp function by using svg.js for fliping up and down an image. I need a side flip function also but I can not be able to implement side flip function by using scale(1,-1). Can anyone help me out?

[image: flip up done]
[image: help me for slide flip]
function flipUp written in personalise.js as under:

```
function flipUp()
{
    var angle = parseInt(target.trans.rotation,10) + 180;
    //if(angle > 360) angle = angle -360
    console.log(angle)
    target.animate().rotate(angle)

    //target.animate().transform('matrix' ,'-1,0,0,-1,0,0')
}
```

And the function is called from design.html as under:

```
<a href="#" onclick="flipUp()"><img src='flip_up.PNG' alt="" height="20" width="20" style='margin-top:-41px;margin-left:267px'></a>
```

Comment: Please provide [`jsfiddle example`](http://jsfiddle.net) of what you currently have.

Comment: how to work with jsfiddle.. i dont know.. each time i put it over there, it doesnot work.. canb you guide me please??

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this wouldn't the need for `svg.js`. You just need to use [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform), in particular [rotate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#rotate).  Also dont forget to add `deg` to the angle.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/frhdbxub/1/)

---

HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="flipUp(this)"><img src='flip_up.PNG' alt="" height="20" width="20" style='margin-top:-41px;margin-left:267px'></a>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
// el is the anchor element (a)
// el.children[0] is the img
// however, this assumes the first child of the anchor element is the img

var angle = 15;

function flipUp(el){

    el.children[0].style.transform = 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)';

    // add 15 degs on every click
    angle += 15;
}
```

Hope this helps and let me know if you have any questions.